# How to migrate VSS 2005 to TFS 2015?

Tags: tfs, migration, visual-sourcesafe

We use VSS 2005. Now we have TFS 2015. How to migrate all data from VSS to TFS 2015 so we keep the history?

I see that there is a guide, but it is for TFS 2008. And Microsoft says it can be outdated, so are there newer guides or some walkthrough?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Direct upgrade to TFS 2015 is not supported for anything older than 2010, so you'll upgrade first from VSS2005 to TFS 2013, then to TFS 2015.

- Upgrade from Visual SourceSafe to TFS 2013, follow article below:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253060(v=vs.120).aspx

- Upgrade from TFS 2013 to TFS 2015, follow:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2015/09/30/migration-update-from-team-foundation-server-tfs-2013-to-tfs-2015-with-reporting-and-sharepoint/

Comment: If the history isn't vital, a tip migration is much faster and easier.